# Make dynamic Y-axis max value and tick interval of highchart using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have created Highchart form php table. Right now Y-axis max. and interval values are fixed. How can I make them dynamic using last four records. Say max. value is 20 from query then intervals will be 5. For max value I got query which returns max. value from 2 column and last 4 records.
Mysql query:

```
 SELECT GREATEST(MAX(step1), MAX(step2)) FROM workflow1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4
```

Highchart script:

```
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    data: {
    table: 'datatable'
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Results',
    style: {
        color: '#FF00FF',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
},
    legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 50,
    padding: 3,
    itemMarginTop: 5,
    itemMarginBottom: 5,
    itemStyle: {
        lineHeight: '14px'
    }
},

yAxis: {

    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    tickInterval: 20,
    allowDecimals: false,
    title: {
        text: 'Time in Sec.'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

});

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand. What is stopping you setting the yAxis properties of max and tickInterval from the results of your database query? Seems to me like you have both parts of the solution already.

Comment: You are right! But I am unable to set that query in variable and put in place of 100 or 20 (max. value and interval).

Comment: Add complete code . How you are creating values in php and bringing these values in javascript code.I am sure its easy. But add code which will help us to give solution. If still not getting, then starting point will be [working-with-data](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro) docs.

Comment: Actually I am new to php and mysql so forgive me for silly mistakes. Here is what I tried: `$test = "SELECT GREATEST(MAX(step1), MAX(step2)) FROM workflow1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$test1 = mysqli_query($conn, $test);
echo $test1; ` but get error : `Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string` error. I was about put variable in place of max. value.

Comment: Do you even need to set fixed intervals? If you don't define values for `min`, `max`, or `tickInterval`, Highcharts will automatically generate a chart based on the current data available.

Comment: I want them flexible, @Mike Zavarello, you saved my time. You can put this in answer.

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad Oh, great! I've written a formal answer per your request. So glad this helped your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't define specific values for `min`, `max`, or `tickInterval`, Highcharts will automatically adjust the axis' maximum value and tick intervals based on the current data available.

The dynamic update Highcharts demo shows how this works (though you may have to wait a bit before it goes above 1 in the example): https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Glad this was helpful for you!